# Google App Engine - missing numpy.core.multiarray

Tags: python, numpy, google-app-engine, google-bigquery

I'm trying to run a webapp from Google App Engine, which accesses bigquery using pandas-gbq. This is the error when I build and run the app:

```
ImportError:
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.
Original error was: No module named numpy.core.multiarray
```

My requirements.txt file has

```
google-api-python-client==1.6.5
google-auth==1.4.1
google-auth-httplib2==0.0.3
numpy==1.14.2
pandas==0.22.0
pandas-gbq==0.3.1
```

These versions for the last 3 work fine outside of the web app in a standard python script. Maybe it's something to do with app engine not using the numpy version specified above, instead using 1.6.1 which is the built-in version: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/built-in-libraries-27

Any tips on how to fix this?

Comment: You can't upload compiled C code in the GAE standard environment, and numpy has compiled code.

Answer (score 3):

Note that Panda library uses C internally and like @JeffO'Neill said in the App Engine Standard Environment all code for the Python runtime environment must be [pure Python](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/runtime#Python_Pure_Python) and it can’t include any libraries that need C extensions or other code that must be compiled.

However, in the [App Engine Flexible Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/) there is no restriction and you can use C modules.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I'll look into using  App Engine flex for this